# Convert list of dicts to CSV in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv, dictionary

I got a list of dictionaries with different length and even different `(key: values)` pairs. For example:

```
[
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'key1': 'someValue', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'anotherKey1': 'anotherValue1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
]
```

I need to create `CSV` file with all of keys as headers and values. If key not in the current dictionary then set the default value (for example '-'). The `CSV` from example should be looking like that:

[image]

I'm trying this code for my list of dictionaries, but it returns an error:

```
listOfDicts = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'key1': 'someValue', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'anotherKey1': 'anotherValue1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
]

keys = listOfDicts[0].keys()
with open('test.csv', 'a') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=keys, delimiter='@')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(listOfDicts)
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'key2'
```

How I can add all unique keys as headers for CSV and fill it values by key?

Comment: You can use `pandas.from_dict()` method, add each row in a loop and save with `df.to.csv(path_to_csv)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `DicitWritter()` `restval` parameter,

> The optional restval parameter specifies the value to be written if
>   the dictionary is missing a key in fieldnames.

and for `fieldnames` parameter use a list of all available keys in a list of dictionaries.

```
import csv


listOfDicts = [
    {'key1': 'value1', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'key1': 'someValue', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2'},
    {'anotherKey': 'anotherValue', 'anotherKey1': 'anotherValue1', 'key1': 'value1', 'key2':'value2', 'key3':'value3'},
]

keys = [i for s in [d.keys() for d in listOfDicts] for i in s]

with open('test.csv', 'a') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, restval="-", fieldnames=keys, delimiter='@')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(listOfDicts)
```

output:

```
$ cat test.csv 
key3@key1@key2@anotherKey@anotherKey1
value3@value1@-@-@-
value3@someValue@value2@-@-
-@value1@value2@anotherValue@-
value3@value1@value2@anotherValue@anotherValue1
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: @KonstantinRusanov accidentally i have erased a important line of code while editing a post. Sorry :) please try now.

Answer (score 3):

To overcome the error, you can collect all the keys before writing the file, like this:

```
keys = set()
for d in listOfDicts:
    keys.update(d.keys())

with open('test.csv', 'a') as output_file:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(
        output_file, fieldnames=keys, restval='-', delimiter='@')
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(listOfDicts)
```

You can use the parameter [`DictWriter.restval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to assign default values for missing keys.

Comment: The `keys` set construction is quite clear here and it's working fine, unlike the single-liner in the accepted answer which doesn't work for me in a very large and sparse dictionary list... Not sure why.